# list which drives query driven batch

Tags: spring-batch

Any spring batch experts out there I could do with your help : I need to create a batch process which returns a list of id's from the database where each id is subsequently used to drive a query that returns a set of records. The resultset (per id)  will be quiet large so how do I get the second query to chunk whilst been driven iteratively from the first query (list of ids)?

All the examples I've come across deal with one query which is subsequently chunked which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- A custom `ItemReader` - Create a wrapper for one of the JDBC based `ItemReader` implementations.  The wrapper would query for the ids and use the delegate to query the chunks.  Your wrapper would need to maintain the state (which ids have been read) for restartability but in general, this would be the easiest option.
- Partitioning - Partitioning by id if you don't have to worry about the order of the ids being processed (each partition = 1 id) would also work.  The partitioning option would only require the custom `Partitioner` implementation.  The rest would be off the shelf components.

Comment: Thanks Michael - this might be more than I require. Is it possible for one itemReader to be the input for another ItemReader? My initial set of ids would be small around 1000. Nevertheless I will look into it. thanks. K

Comment: The first option (the custom `ItemReader`) is the closest we get to chaining item readers.